# Why won't the text of my <p> change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, query-string

I have a function which takes a value from query strings and puts it inside a **p** element:

```
var globalCodice = querystring('codice');
var globalCodiceTesto = globalCodice.valueOf();
var myOfferta = $('#currentOfferta');

$('#currentOfferta').text(globalCodiceTesto); //THIS DOES NOT WORK
```

where **globalCodice** is the queryString, obtained from this method:

```
function querystring(key) {
   var re=new RegExp('(?:\\?|&)'+key+'=(.*?)(?=&|$)','gi');
   var r=[], m;
   while ((m=re.exec(document.location.search)) != null) r.push(m[1]);
   return r;
}
```

markup:

```
<!-- header -->

    <div id='titleHeader' class='header'>
        <h3>Dettaglio Offerta</h3>
        <p id='currentOfferta' style='color:white !important'>OMFG</p>
    </div><!-- /header -->
```

But in the end the text never gets changed. I've tried different things and nothing seems to work. Does anyone have something to share with me in order to make this work?

edit: globalCodice and globalCodiceTesto are retrieved correctly, as the p element. The only thing that does not work is the .text() line.

Comment: Try debugging with Firebug or at least put an alert to make sure your getting the value for globalCodiceTesto

Comment: read the edit: it is getting the right value.

Comment: Like the answer said, make sure you are not setting it until the document is ready, otherwise it will never show up.  I assumed it was wrapped with document ready, but I think that might be your issue

Comment: style='color:white' 

I hope your background is not white :D

Comment: it is wrapped with document ready. Still does not work.

Comment: no, the background is dark red, if your really want to know

Comment: Did you try debugging with firefox?  How are you certain that the values are correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does

```
typeof(globalCodiceTesto)
```

return `String`? What happens if you do

```
$('#currentOfferta').text("af");
```

?

Comment: Th0rndike Did you try this?  What happened?

Comment: This is not the solution, but it took me to the solution. What worked was forcing the globalCodiceTesto to be a string. I did this: var globalCodiceTesto = globalCodice.valueOf()+"";

Comment: I was typing an answer mentioning the fact of globalCodiceTesto not being a string... glad I saw this comment first! @Willem Mulder +'d by the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#currentOfferta').text(globalCodiceTesto);
});
```

Comment: your function returns an object, not a string :|

Comment: of course it does, unless you call the right url with the right parameters. (if there is no parameter "codice" in your url, it will find nothing)

Comment: That is why he does the valueOf call and sets the return of that to globalCodiceTesto

Comment: `console.log(typeof(globalCodiceTesto))` == object

Comment: Ahh I guess that the exec call doesnt return a string, good catch